# Flask url_for adding trailing slash with gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am using Flask and when developing locally, all this works fine. However, when deployed using nginx with a proxy pass through gunicorn, the `url_for` seems to be adding a trailing `/` to the url which is causing errors when pulling the json data off the url. Here's the relevant code:

```
@app.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    name = request.form['name'];
    email = request.form['email']
    data = json.dumps({"name": name, "email": email})
    return redirect(url_for('.record', data=data))

@app.route("/record")
def record():
    // error here because of trailing /
    data = json.loads(request.args['data'])
    //... more code
```

I'm pretty new to using Flask and super new to gunicorn so if I'm missing any required info to get help, just let me know. Here's the proxy_pass config in nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

And then I'm just running gunicorn as a service with:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app
```

Example breaking URL

```
https://<ipaddress>/record?data=%7B%22name%22%3A+%22fdaf%22%2C+%22email%22%3A+%22fsd%40sfd.com%22%7D/
```

Comment: Can you change `http://localhost:8000` to `http://localhost:8000/` and see if it helps?

Comment: You have tried `strict_slashes=False`?

Comment: Neither suggestion works.